# How to change JDK version temporarily for mvn

Tags: linux, maven, terminal, settings

I have used the following command to set the java version temporarily

```
export JAVA_HOME=/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

but when i run `mvn -v` I see it's pointing to java 7

so how to change `JAVA_HOME` temporarily and see the effect in `mvn -v` ??

Comment: did you run the same commands in the same console or in two different consoles?

Comment: I just tried both in Windows and Linux and I got the change correctly. Did you try to check your export with an echo command?

Comment: when i ran java -version it shows 1.8. but mvn -v points to 1.7. echo $JAVA_HOME also shows 1.8

Comment: Is `/etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0/bin/java -version` returning the Java version you want to use? ps you don't need to define `PATH`.

Comment: but is your intend to run mvn with different jdk or to compile and test classes with different jdk? (the two things are slightly different and you can configure the maven compiler and surefire plugin to use a different jdk via pom configuration even temporarily)

Comment: @A.DiMatteo I know i can achieve this using pom. I am not looking for that. I need 1.8 when i run mvn -v

Comment: @JoaoMorais yes it returns 1.8

Comment: `mvn` is a Bash script. Use `bash -x mvn -version` in order to see commands and variables being used. Perhaps this will help.

Comment: @JoaoMorais thanks man its helps a lot. Now I downloaded another maven and when i run ./mvn -v, i get 1.8. thanks again

Comment: Which Maven version do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by downloading another maven. and running

```
./mavendir/bin/mvn -v
```

Now it works fine